# Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations on Kylin

Tags: permissions

I've created a test account on Kylin, funded it from a faucet, bought RAM and deployed a contract.  when I try to call a contract method I get the above error

my call attempt is made using cleos and since my new account was not in the local wallet I added the private key such that I can see it when I execute:

```
cleos wallet keys
```

additionally, I created the account locally such that if I issue:

```
cleos get accounts <my-public-key>
```

I see the account.  I can also:

```
cleos get account <my-account>
```

and it shows me that the owner and active permissions are bound to the correct public key.  however, when I call the method:

```
cleos -u https://kylin.eos.dfuse.io/ push action <my-account> deposit '["cust1", "8,BTC"]' -p <my-account>@active
```

it fails.  just in case, I've also run:

```
cleos set account permission <my-account> active --add-code
```

but to no avail.  what else can I check?

**Appendix I**

for completeness, here's the rest of the error:

> Error Details: transaction declares authority
>   '{"actor":"MyAccount","permission":"active"}', but does not have
>   signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions
>   [{"actor":"MyAccount","permission":"eosio.code"}], provided keys
>   [], and a delay max limit of 3888000000 ms pending console output:

I notice the "provided keys" is empty.  as previously stated, if the key required is for my account, I can see it listed.  if it's for eosio.code, I don't know how I would get that

Answer (score 0):

Check if the contract has been successfully deployed to your account.

1. Check if the wallet is unlocked, if not then unlock it:

`cleos wallet unlock -n <wallet_name> --password <wallet_password>`

2. Check if you have the required key pair using:

`cleos wallet private_keys -n <wallet_name> --password <wallet_password>`

3. Then push the action.

   `cleos -u https://kylin.eos.dfuse.io push action <my-account/contract_name> deposit '["cust1", "8,BTC"]' -p <my-account>@active`

**contract_name is the account_name to which the contract is deployed.**

Check if the endpoint is working properly.

If the contract is deployed to your account, you'll need only your keys.